# How to put a table next to a plot?

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment

I made a plot and a table, and I want to put the table next to the plot, how can I do that?

[image: screenshot]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=13cm,
]
\addplot coordinates{(-3,9) (-2,7) (-1,5) (0,3) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
X & Y  \\
-3 &  9  \\
-2 & 7  \\
-1 & 5  \\
0 & 3  \\
1 & 1  \\
2 & -1  \\
3 & -3  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Well, if they are as in the snippet you show, you could just remove the empty line between the two. The vertical alignment would perhaps not be perfect though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried but only puts the table half-way down the plot, so it does not look nice.

Comment: Every box has a baseline.  The default baseline for tikzpicture is the bottom, and the default baseline for a tabular is the center.  Both can be adjusted.  Or you can use \raisebox{\height}{...} on both of them.

Comment: The link to the picture is broken; you should use the interface to Imgur: click on the “Image” button above the editing window and follow the instructions, rather than linking to another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you don't need individual captions for these.

If you remove the paragraph break (the empty line) between the two they are placed on the same line. The vertical alignment is a bit off, because the bottom of the `tikzpicture` is placed on the current line, and so is the middle of the `tabular`. While the vertical 'anchoring' of the `tabular` can be modified with the optional argument, e.g. `\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}` (`t` and `c` are also allowed, the latter being the default), it is better to modify the vertical placement of the `tikzpicture` on the line.

There are two modifications you need to do: add `baseline` as an option to the `tikzpicture`, and add `anchor=center` to the options for the `axis`, i.e.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
     ...
    anchor=center]
```

Another option is to place the entire `tabular` in a `\node` inside the `tikzpicture`. You can do this by adding a node name to the axis, with `name=somenodename`, and place the node with `\node [right=of somenodename] {\begin{tabular}{cc}..\end{tabular}};`. This requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

As a final tip: with the `pgfplotstable` package you can enter the data once, and use them in both the plot and the table. That way you don't have to repeat information. I've added an example of this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y  
-3  9  
-2  7  
-1 5  
0 3  
1 1  
2 -1 
3 -3
}\mydata

\usepackage{booktabs}

\pgfplotstableset{every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=13cm,
anchor=center
]
\addplot coordinates{(-3,9) (-2,7) (-1,5) (0,3) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
X & Y  \\
-3 &  9  \\
-2 & 7  \\
-1 & 5  \\
0 & 3  \\
1 & 1  \\
2 & -1  \\
3 & -3  \\
\end{tabular}


\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=13cm,
name=myplot
]
\addplot table[x=X,y=Y] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\node [right=of myplot] {\pgfplotstabletypeset\mydata};
\end{tikzpicture}


\newpage


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=13cm,
anchor=center
]
\addplot table[x=X,y=Y] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstabletypeset\mydata

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of second alternative in the code above:

[image]